# Erro de leitura com a função fread do pacote data.table

Tags: r, data.frame

Ao baixar o banco de dados sobre valores de diárias e passagens de 2019 do portal da transparência http://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/download-de-dados/viagens, utilizei o código abaixo para ler o arquivo de diárias recebidas no ano de 2019, porém tenho recebido alguns erros com a função fread e erros com a função read.delim, pois nesse último caso ao ler a coluna "Valor diárias" os valores não são reconhecidos corretamentes. Segue os códigos com os respectivos erros:

```
rm(list=ls())
library("tidyverse")
library("readr")
library("data.table")
library("stringr")
library("lubridate")
#unzip("2019_20190630_Viagens.zip")
options(datatable.fread.input.cmd.message=FALSE)
Diaria2019_Via <- "iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 2019_Viagem.csv"
Diaria2019 <- data.table::fread(Diaria2019_Via,dec = ",")


Warning messages:
1: In data.table::fread(Diaria2019_Via, dec = ",") :
  Found and resolved improper quoting in first 100 rows. If the fields are not quoted (e.g. field separator does not appear within any field), try quote="" to avoid this warning.
2: In data.table::fread(Diaria2019_Via, dec = ",") :
  Stopped early on line 7378. Expected 16 fields but found 18. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line: <<"0000000000015769552";"Realizada";"53000";"Ministério do Desenvolvimento Regional";"53000";"Ministério do Desenvolvimento Regional - Unidades com vínculo direto";"***.043.57*-**";"ARMIN AUGUSTO BRAUN";"";"20190115";"20190116";"São Paulo/SP";"Representar a Secretaria Nacional de Proteção e Defesa Civil - SEDEC, no Seminário "Proteção e Defesa Civil Aplicada", onde Ministrará palestra sobre "Apoio Federal na Resposta a Desastres"; participará reunião com pessoal do Hospital Albert Eins>>
```

A mensagem acima sugere usar `quote=""` e `fill=NULL`, no entanto, nenhum deles funciona. O código abaixo faz a leitura incorreta da coluna de Valor de diárias:

```
Diaria_2019 <- read_delim("2019_Viagem.csv", 
                          ";", escape_double = FALSE, locale = locale(decimal_mark = ".",encoding = "ISO-8859-1"), 
                          trim_ws = TRUE)
```

Alguém sugere alguma outra função que possa ler corretamente o banco de dados `2019_Viagem.csv`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O arquivo está preenchido de maneira incorreta na fonte. Até onde sei, vai ser impossível ler ele, desta maneira, dentro do R. Descobri isso ao rodar, no terminal, o comando

```
cat 2019_Viagem.csv | awk -F";" '{print NF-1}' | head -7379 | tail -3
```

Indo por partes, o que este comando faz é o seguinte:

1. `cat 2019_Viagem.csv`: imprime o conteúdo do arquivo `2019_Viagem.csv` na tela do terminal
2. `awk -F";" '{print NF-1}'`: a linguagem `awk` procura por todas as ocorrências de `;` em cada linha do arquivo `2019_Viagem.csv` e as conta. Como `;` é o separador de colunas, um arquivo com 16 colunas deve possuir 15 caracteres do tipo `;`
3. `head -7379` e `tail -3`: fazem a mesma função do `R`, no qual `head` mostra as *n* primeiras linhas de um arquivo e `tail`, as *m* últimas

O caracter `|` serve para concatenar os comandos, numa função idêntica ao comando `%>%` dos pacotes `magrittR` ou `dplyr`. Assim, o que recebi foi o resultado

```
15
17
15
```

Isto significa que existem 16 colunas nas linhas 7377 e 7379 do arquivo `2019_Viagem.csv`, enquanto na linha 7378 existem 18 colunas. Perceba que este resultado tem tudo a ver com o warning que tu recebeu na tua tentativa:

```
2: In data.table::fread(Diaria2019_Via, dec = ",") :
  Stopped early on line 7378. Expected 16 fields but found 18.
```

Como o R não sabe como lidar com esta incongruência entre as quantidades de colunas entre as linhas, tu acaba tendo problemas com a leitura destes dados. A título de curiosidade, estas são as três linhas cujas quantidades de `;` eu contei e exibi acima:

```
"0000000000015769550";"Realizada";"30000";"Minist�rio da Justi�a e Seguran�a P�blica";"30108";"Departamento de Pol�cia Federal";"***.000.00*-**";"Informa��es protegidas por sigilo";"Informa��es protegidas por sigilo";"20190117";"20190117";"Informa��es protegidas por sigilo";"Informa��o protegida por sigilo nos termos da legisla��o vigente";",00";"3792,34";",00"
"0000000000015769552";"Realizada";"53000";"Minist�rio do Desenvolvimento Regional";"53000";"Minist�rio do Desenvolvimento Regional - Unidades com v�nculo direto";"***.043.57*-**";"ARMIN AUGUSTO BRAUN";"";"20190115";"20190116";"S�o Paulo/SP";"Representar a Secretaria Nacional de Prote��o e Defesa Civil - SEDEC, no Semin�rio "Prote��o e Defesa Civil Aplicada", onde Ministrar� palestra sobre "Apoio Federal na Resposta a Desastres"; participar� reuni�o com pessoal do Hospital Albert Einstein para prepara��o de Simulado de Preven��o de desastres; participar� de reuni�o com Diretor do Centro Nacional de Monitoramento e Alertas de Desastres Naturais - CEMADEN, que ser�o realizados no dia 16 de janeiro de 2019.";"475,70";"2201,04";",00"
"0000000000015769553";"Realizada";"30000";"Minist�rio da Justi�a e Seguran�a P�blica";"30108";"Departamento de Pol�cia Federal";"***.000.00*-**";"Informa��es protegidas por sigilo";"Informa��es protegidas por sigilo";"20190101";"20190103";"Informa��es protegidas por sigilo";"Informa��o protegida por sigilo nos termos da legisla��o vigente";"725,96";",00";",00"
```

Eu vejo duas linhas de ação para resolver o teu problema:

A primeira seria corrigir manualmente as linhas problemáticas. Sim, são várias linhas com problemas. Abaixo mostro uma tabela com a quantidade de ocorrências de `;` no conjunto de dados inteiro, obtida através do comando `cat 2019_Viagem.csv | awk -F";" '{print NF-1}' | sort | uniq -c`:

```
266878 15
  2929 16
  1282 17
   500 18
   521 19
   253 20
    80 21
    54 22
    27 23
    31 24
     6 25
     6 26
     2 27
     7 28
     3 29
     4 33
     2 37
```

Veja que 266878 linhas tem 15 separadores de colunas como se espera, 2929 tem 16 e assim por diante. Chegamos ao cúmulo de 2 linhas terem 37 `;`. Particularmente, não vejo como criar um algoritmo que consiga tratar de todas as exceções que podem surgir ao lidar com um conjunto de dados problemático assim.

A outra solução que vejo é entrar em contato direto com quem fornece estes dados e comentar a respeito destas incongruências. Quem sabe surge alguém no governo federal para te ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Estão disponíveis em http://portaldatransparencia.gov.br/download-de-dados/viagens os novos arquivos, com as devidas correções. Agradeço a ajuda de vocês. Caso necessário, entrem em contato diretamente pelos canais oficiais da CGU (LAI, E-Ouv, Facebook e Telegram). Mais informações em: http://cgu.gov.br/.

Comment: Obrigado CGU, parabéns pelo trabalho e pela pronta correção dos arquivos!