# Remover linhas de um banco de dados problemático no R

Tags: banco-de-dados, r

Há alguns dias fiz uma pergunta no stack, conforme [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/397265/erro-de-leitura-com-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-fread-do-pacote-data-table/397291#397291). A resposta que recebi do prof. @Marcus Nunes mostra que menos de 10% das linhas possuem mais de 15 separadores do tipo `;`. Nesse caso, desejo apagar todas as linhas com mais de 15 `;` para separar colunas. Um primeiro código para proceder esta limpeza e gerar um novo banco de dados segue abaixo, no entanto, o mesmo não funcionou corretamente. Gostaria de receber alguma sugestão de como proceder para atingir meu objetivo?

```
library("tidyverse")
library("stringr")

teste <- readLines("2019_Viagem.csv")
count <- str_count(teste, ';')
teste <- teste[count==15]
write.csv2(teste,"plan2019.csv",row.names = FALSE)
Diaria2019_Via <- "iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 plan2019.csv"
Diaria2019 <- data.table::fread(Diaria2019_Via, dec = ",")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creio que o seguinte código R, com algum `awk` preparatório, faz o que a pergunta pede.

Primeiro vou redirecionar a saída do comando `iconv` da pergunta para um ficheiro novo, o ficheiro `2019_Viagem_UTF8.csv`.

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 2019_Viagem.csv > 2019_Viagem_UTF8.csv
```

É este ficheiro que vou processar.

Agora vou mudar ligeiramente a linha de comando na resposta do @MarcusNunes para ter um ficheiro de texto com os números de *colunas* de cada linha e não os números de `";"`. Na verdade é o mesmo, mais tarde no R seria só comparar com `15` e não com `16` como vou fazer.
A nova linha de comando é a seguinte.

```
cat 2019_Viagem.csv | awk -F";" '{print NF}' > colunas.txt
```

Isto cria um ficheiro só com quantas colunas tem cada linha, um número por linha de `colunas.txt`.

Finalmente o código R.

1. Ler quantas colunas tem cada linha do ficheiro `2019_Viagem_UTF8.csv`.
2. Ler esse ficheiro.
3. Ficar só com as linhas que queremos, com 16 colunas.
4. Criar um `data.frame`, usando `read.csv2` com o argumento `text = txt`.
5. E guardar em disco como ficheiro csv.

Aqui vai

```
colunas <- scan(file = "colunas.txt")
txt <- readLines("2019_Viagem_UTF8.csv")
txt <- txt[colunas == 16]
limpo <- read.csv2(text = txt)
rm(txt)
dim(limpo)
#[1] 125695     16

write.csv2(limpo, file = "plan2019.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

**Nota:** Na pergunta está `plan2018.csv` e não 2019. Creio que isso é um erro que corrigi.

Comment: Muito bom @Rui Barradas, obrigado!